# If there are continuous surjections $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$, are $X, Y$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

If there are continuous surjections $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$ are $X, Y$ homeomorphic?  This is not homework.  Just to trying to review some topology.

Comment: Ah, it looks like this is a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/169468/264

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Let $X=\mathbb{S}^1$ and $Y=[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

See for even stronger examples the answers to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30661/non-homeomorphic-spaces-that-have-continuous-bijections-between-them