# Topology on the set of all separable Hausdorff topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, hyperspace

It is well-known ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723948/how-big-can-a-separable-hausdorff-space-be), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190271/question-about-the-cardinality-of-a-space)) that the cardinality of a separable Hausdorff topological space is at most $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. Therefore, the collection $\mathcal{A}$ of all (homeomorphism classes of) separable Hausdorff topological spaces is a set. Can the set $\mathcal{A}$ be equipped with a natural topology?

Comment: Much narrower, but you might be amused by the existence of a natural metric on the space of (isometry types of) compact metric spaces, namely the **Gromov-Hausdorff metric**.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but an example where a topology is put on a certain collection of topologies on a set is cited in [this mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/67806/15780). Regarding that answer, see my 3 June 2002 sci.math post [Incestuous Mathematics](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/H0FeC0NTGDU/m/EhuB6saiBhMJ).

Comment: Every partial order has a natural topology (subbasis of upward and downward sets). Is there a natural partial order on these spaces?

Comment: Define a relation $A\leq B$ if $A$ is homeomorphic to some subspace of $B.$ Can we show this is a partial order on $\mathcal A?$ This essentially means, if $A,B$ are separable and Hausdorff, then $A\leq B$ and $B\leq A$ implies $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic. But I'mnot sure this is true.

Comment: Doesn't work - we tried that in another post a while back. Think about [0,1] and (0,1).

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: FYI, I think a version of your relation was introduced by Fréchet in 1910. See the page references to Sierpiński's topology book cited in [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/169529/13130). For example, on p. 130 (lines $-18$ to $-15)$ Sierpiński says: "If $P$ is homeomorphic with a subset of $Q$ but $Q$ is not homeomorphic with any subset of $P,$ then $P$ is said to have a smaller dimensional type than $Q$ and we write $dP<dQ$ (or $dQ>dP).$ Clearly if $dP<dQ$ and $dQ \leq dR$ then $dP < dR.$"

Comment: All this interested commentary and not any voting that would actually help the question receive an answer

Comment: There is no collection, let alone a set, of homeomorphism classes of separable Hausdorff topological spaces. What you can do is this: Fix any set $S$ of cardinality $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. Then you can define the set $\mathfrak H$ of all  separable Hausdorff topological spaces whose underlying sets are subsets of $S$. Each  separable Hausdorff topological spaces is homeomorphic to an element of $\mathfrak H$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you, this is what I meant

Comment: For anyone thinking about @StevenClontz idea regarding a natural partial order on these spaces, may want to have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4818460/1210477 to see a list of failing candidates. [To clarify, the idea itself is a good one, just wanted to reference some natural approaches to it that won't work]